# Issue with ListView and TextView scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app contains a ListView on top and a TextView on bottom.  I want to scroll text in the TextView automatically.  But it is not scrolling, i also submitted layout xml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1" /> 

   <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

thanks for a solution

Comment: Drag scroll-view and make new layout inside scroll-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set attribute `android:scrollingCache="true"` in your ListView

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scrollingCache="true"
   android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: when ListView is focused content of TextView is not scrolling.  Is it possible ?

Comment: do you want a horizontal scroll in your text view?
then you need to put your text view inside a `HorizontalScrollView`
Documentation Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it solves your problem. it'll help others in identifying the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to scrolling issue, is add text view inside horizontalScrollview.

And as you are adding textview below to ListView, you wont be able to textView, if listView height exceeds device height, so I would suggest you to make LinearLayout parent of ListView and a RelativeLayout parent to the LinearLayout and HorizontalScrollView. Let LinearLayouts Params to width->fill-Parent and layout-height=fill-parent, and above textView, and HorizontalLayout's Params to width=fill-parent, and height= wrap-content, and align bottom to parent.

Update by Some Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                   <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView" />
     </LinearLayout> 

     <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_align_parent_bottom="true">

                          <TextView  
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_conetent" 
                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                     android:text="@string/hello"
                                     android:singleLine="true"
                                     />
     </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am a newbie, i get confused.  can you explain ?

Comment: i update xml file with above change, but no change in the result

Comment: change textview width to wrap_content instead of fill_parent

Comment: @techcent what is the problem you facing currently ?